# download multiple images on iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use this code to download images to my iOS App from web.

https://github.com/AshFurrow/AFImageDownloader

```
[AFImageDownloader imageDownloaderWithURLString:@"http://static.ashfurrow.com.s3.amazonaws.com/github/worked.jpg" autoStart:YES completion:^(UIImage *decompressedImage) {
self.imageView.image = decompressedImage;
}];
```

As you can see this code downloads only one image...

How can I download more images at once?

Let's say my images names will be like that:

**xy.png where x is a number from 1 to 999, and y is a number from 1 to 4
For example: 1651.png, 1652.png, 1653.png, 1654.png - as you can see, last digit of my image names is "y", from 1 to 4... THIS IS THE RULE, all my image names ends with 1, 2, 3, 4.**

But, 165 is "x", so the next set of images will be 1661.png, 1662.png, 1663.png, 1664.png

I hope you got my point.. So, i need to download all images with names from 11.png to 9994.png

Any Ideas? How to download using above code and save them with the original name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, you could just call that same function in a background thread in a loop. Secondly, I really hope those are very small images, and even if they are that is a lot of images to be forcing the user to download.

Comment: yep. they are small, max 200kb one image... well, i can use loop for "x" for my first part of image name, what about second part "y"??? can you give me a example of loop with two initializations? I'm new :)

Comment: Why can you not use a for loop for the y part? And 200kb for 10,000 images? That's 2GB of download! Some data plans don't even go that high.

Comment: I use this code for a game like 4 pics 1 song game... so, user will download up to 1000-4000 images, no more....

Comment: NO.  ABSOLUTELY NOT.  DO NOT DOWNLOAD 1000-4000 200kb IMAGES.  If I caught an app using that much space I would delete it in an instant and call it a crap app (I would use more colorful words in my 1 star review).  Only download the images you need to, so if it's like 4 pics 1 song, download like 12 pics so you have the first round downloaded and the next two cached and use a for loop like @Jsdodgers said

Answer (score -1):

Ever heard of a nested for loop?

```
static const NSUInteger xLowerBound = 1;
static const NSUInteger xUpperBound = 999;
static const NSUInteger yLowerBound = 1;
static const NSUInteger yUpperBound = 4;

static NSString *const path = @"http://static.ashfurrow.com.s3.amazonaws.com/";
static NSString *const imgExt = @"jpg";

for (NSUInteger x = xLowerBound; x <= xUpperBound; x++) {
    for (NSUInteger y = yLowerBound; y <= yLowerBound; y++) {
        NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu%lu", (unsigned long)x, (unsigned long)y];
        NSString *urlString = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[combined stringByAppendingPathExtension:imgExt]];

        [AFImageDownloader imageDownloaderWithURLString:urlString autoStart:YES completion:^(UIImage *decompressedImage) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

That said, you probably shouldn't be doing this. =P