# for loop with two integers

Tags: objective-c

i'm new here. I would like to know, how to use **for loop** with 2 integers.

Let's say:

```
for (int  x = 1, int y = 1; x <=200, y <=4; x++, y++)
```

I need it, because I have some images on my web server, with the following names:

1501.png, 1502.png, 1503.png, 1504.png

1511.png, 1512.png, 1513.png, 1514.png

As you can see, last digit from my image name is y and first 3 digits is x.

I want to use something like:

```
[@"mywebsite/%i%i.png", x , y]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The correct way to perform two tests in a for loop is like this: `for (int  x = 1, int y = 1; x <=200 && y <=4; x++, y++)` but that won't do what you want. You need to use nested loops as many answers have pointed out.

Comment: @0x7fffffff I was tempted to answer this question by saying to use a nested `for` loop. Has anyone done that yet?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198363/download-multiple-images-on-ios-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much clearer to put one loop inside the other:

```
for (int x = 1; x <=200; x++) {
    for(int y = 1; y <=4; y++) {
        // [@"mywebsite/%i%i.png", x , y]
    }
}
```

I'd also suggest more descriptive names than x and y

Comment: Depending on the filename, you may want to use a format of `%03i%i`. This will give you 0011 through 2004 instead of 11 through 2004.

Answer (score 4):

You would do something like this: (Nested loop)

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 200; x++) {
     for (int y = 1; y <=4; y++) {
         //Do your logic here like
         NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mywebsite/%d/%d.png", x, y];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(x=1; x<=200; x++)
{
    for(y=1; y<=4; y++)
    {
        NSString * filename = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"mywebsite/%i%i.png", x, y];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> *I need it, because I have some images on my web server, with the following names:*

you could also use one for-loop and alter the control variable.

```
for(int i = 1; i<2005; ++i){
    if (! (i% 5 == 0)) {
        NSLog(@"%d", i);
    } else {
        i+= 5;
    }
}
```

output:

```
…
1501
1502
1503
1504
1511
1512
1513
1514
1521
1522
1523
1524
…
```

---

or more general:

```
int COLUMN = 4;
int ROW = 10;
for(int i = 1; i<2000+(COLUMN+1); ++i){
    if (! (i% ROW == (COLUMN+1))) {
        NSLog(@"mywebsite/%04i.png", i);
    } else {
        i+= ROW -(COLUMN+1);
    }
}
```

output

```
…
mywebsite/1501.png
mywebsite/1502.png
mywebsite/1503.png
mywebsite/1504.png
mywebsite/1511.png
mywebsite/1512.png
mywebsite/1513.png
mywebsite/1514.png
mywebsite/1521.png
mywebsite/1522.png
mywebsite/1523.png
mywebsite/1524.png
…
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use nested forloops.

I think something like this would accomplish what you're after

```
 for (int i = 10 i <= 200; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <=4; j++) {
        //Do something with the i and j value for file name.        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Impossible**: If you used 2 integers in one loop as suggested, x and y would equal the same thing. They both start at 1 and count up by 1 each time the loop goes round. You're saying that while x<=200 OR/AND y<=4. This accomplishes nothing since x=y the whole time. I would vote Nick's answer down if I had the rep.

**The correct solution** to the problem you are having is *nested loops*, as mentioned a bunch of times previously, but the above answers lack an explanation and simply contain code, which is useless if you don't know how to use it.

**Code**

```
for(i=1; i<=200; i++)
{
    for(j=1; j<=4; j++)
    {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

**Explanation**: This code basically says, for each time i increases by one (all the way up to 200), j will have counted from 1-4 inside the nested loop.

Answer (score -1):

Whether this really solves your immediate problem or not I thought I'd answer the real question being asked here. `For loop with two integers`.

```
int x, y;
for (x = 1, y = 1; x <= 200 || y<= 4; x++, y++)
```

Comment: You can do this: `for (int x = 1, y = 1; ...`